# C# How to print multiple pictureboxes

Tags: c#, printing, picturebox

I have 2 pictureboxes: pb1 and pb2. Pb1 can be dragged and dropped, pb2 cannot. Pb1 can also be resized.

What i want is, when pb1 is inside pb2, both (pb1 and pb2) must be printed. And pb1 must keep it's sizes. When a look at the prinpreview, is see that pb1 has it's original sizes.

So, how can i print these 2 printboxes and make sure pb1 keep it's resized size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's less then optimal i'm sure, but you can draw the contents of the resized picture to a new bitmap via `Pb1.DrawToBitmap` and reset the Pb1 image to the new image and print.

I should mention I haven't printed from pictureboxes before so I don't understand the whole problem.